# Covert a local image to blob

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

A local image is loaded & displayed in a tab and we want to get a `blob` (or `dataURL`) of the image on `contextMenus.onClicked`.

Normally, `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` can be used on remotely hosted image but that would cause an error on a local image.

Similarly, the following in the background script fails:

```js
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = info.srcUrl;
  // Security Error: Content at moz-extension://.../background.html may not load or link to file:///...128.png
});
```

Note: `new Image()` fails in Chrome MV3 service worker.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Image is not defined
```

Currently, using `tabs.executeScript` to inject a script into the page context, a `canvas` can be created and converted to `blob` (or `dataURL`) and passed back to the background script.

Is there any other (better) way to get a `blob` (or `dataURL`) of the local image (without injecting a script into the page)?

Comment: In Firefox the only way to load a file:// URL is to `fetch` it inside the content script that runs in a tab with the *same* file:// URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm Running `fetch` from a content script would be a similar method to creating a `canvas` in the content script. I was wondering if there was a way to do it (directly in the background script) and without resorting to content script.

Comment: There should be none as it was intentionally removed in FF68.